# Loop through collection and filter it based by current logged-in user's level

Tags: doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-3.4

I'm working on a RPG game in Symfony 3.4 and I have a NPCEntity array passed to a twig view via controller. I used the code below to filter some data about the NPCs:
Show NPCs who are 5 levels above the current user's level.

**Twig view:**

```
  {% for npc in npcs | filter(npc => npc.level < app.user.level+5) %}
  <td>{{ npc.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ npc.level }}</td>
```

However, I had to create separate entity for the level system and I made the NPC Entity's $level property ManyToOne mapped by the Level Entity's $npcs property which returns an array collection and now I'm stuck in filtering the data in the view.

**Level Entity:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NPCType", mappedBy="level")
 */
private $npcs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->npcs = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**NPC Entity:**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Level")
 */
private $level;
```

**My Controller:**

```
class BattlesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/battles", name="battles")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $auth_checker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
        if ($auth_checker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            $npcs = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:NPCType')
                ->findAll();
            return $this->render('default/battles.html.twig', array('npcs' => $npcs));
        } else {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other people helped me figure it out, I made a repository for my Entity and there I made a function to filter the NPC levels based on the current logged in user.

**NPCTypeRepository:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class NPCTypeRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllBetween($currentLevel, $limitLevel) {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');

        return $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('n.level', $currentLevel, $limitLevel))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
          }
}
```

**Updated action in my BattlesController:**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $npcs = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(NPCType::class)->findAllBetween($user->getLevel(), $user->getLevel() + 5);
        return $this->render('default/battles.html.twig', array('npcs' => $npcs));
    }
```